# Downloading an Xbox One profile to an External Hard Drive

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I have some friends who are "running low on space" and think that "profiles take up a lot of space" (they don't) on their Xbox One.
Is there some way - like you can on the Xbox 360 - to download an Xbox Live profile to a USB Drive?

Comment: How do they know profiles take up a lot of space?

Comment: I doubt that the profiles take up a lot of space compared to the games that take up 20-50 GBs each.  If they want more disk space they will need to uninstall some games or get an external hard drive

Comment: profiles on 360 and on xb1 are a few megabytes. games, and some apps, take up a lot more space.

Comment: Frank, they are low on space and don't want to waste more. I'm not saying that profiles take a lot of space; they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Microsoft removed this possibility on the Xbox One due to the Xbox 360 Mass Profile Modding, and they typically don't take up more than 16 MegaBytes of space for a 1 000 000 G Player. Xbox One minimally comes with a 500GB Hard Drive built in.

External Drives lose data much more easily than internals as well, accounting for quite a lot of "AAAaaaAAaHhhH my profile is corrupt!!!11!1" support tickets. ((Yes, there was a thread with that name a few years back on the forum.))

If their profile is indeed taking up a lot of space, somewhere along the line it has become corrupt-or they frequent a game that repeatedly adds bloatware to their profile itself.

Xbox system and updates usually take about 25% of your available storage, which you can do nothing about.

The biggest offenders are typically "But I paid $60 for that!" games, followed by games in general, poorly built apps, and Xbox general software instability.

Don't try this at home kids-but there is theory floating around that there is a way to measure profile size using a Windows 10 PC, and/or OneDrive; assuming you no longer have access to a 360.